# execinfo.h: No such file or directory while installing VIC5.0.1 on windows using cygwin

Tags: c, gcc, cygwin

I am installing VIC5.0.1 using cygwin on windows 7 and while giving the `make` command, it shows:

```
 fatal error: execinfo.h: No such file or directory
```

The above error is there so many times in cygwin terminal, whats wrong in this?

Comment: Related: https://www.gnu.org/software/gnulib/manual/html_node/execinfo_002eh.html (1st hit on gxxgle, BTW)

Comment: @alk can you elaborate what should I do here, I have no idea about it.Thanks

Comment: Where did you get the sources from?

Answer (score 2):

The software as it is can not be built on cygwin and on several other platforms as the header is specific of `glibc`.

In the link provided by `alk` is clearly reported

> This header file is missing on some platforms: Mac OS X 10.3, FreeBSD
>   6.0, NetBSD 5.0, OpenBSD 3.8, Minix 3.1.8, AIX 5.1, HP-UX 11, IRIX 6.5, OSF/1 5.1, Solaris 10, Cygwin, mingw, MSVC 14, Interix 3.5, BeOS, Android 9.0.

I can only guess that the software is only supported on a Linux platform.
There is no evidence of effort to make it multi platform.

Comment: Yes the VIC model is designed for linux platform but the earlier versions of VIC are installed on windows using cygwin, but this latest version VIC5.0.1 has this issue. So it cant be installed on windows?

Comment: As it is can not be compiled. Of course you can try to patch it